# Trying to stream a video loop using FFMPEG. However, I keep getting the error "Cannot Write the Headers Server returned 400 Bad Request"

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, tcp, rtsp

I am using `mediamtx` for starting RTSP server. The command that I am using for ffmpeg is as follows:

`ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i ./clouds.mp4 -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://localhost:8554`

The tried various different options but not luck. I am not getting the ffmpeg to stream the video.

The file details are as follows:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from './clouds.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2023-01-12T20:44:34.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:56.34, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2952 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, 2758 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-01-12T20:44:34.000000Z
      handler_name    : Vimeo Artax Video Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : AVC Coding
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-01-12T20:44:34.000000Z
      handler_name    : Vimeo Artax Audio Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mpeg4 (native))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
```

The error on `mediamtx` terminal window is:

```
2023/05/08 17:30:43 INF [RTSP] [session 298895e1] created by 127.0.0.1:38024
2023/05/08 17:30:43 INF [RTSP] [conn 127.0.0.1:38024] closed (invalid path)
```

Comment: every single time ffmpeg is mentioned in mediamtx docs, the url for the stream is like `rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream` ... which is different to what you are using

Comment: Yeah. I guess I was not supposed to give the root path. That worked. I don't know why it didn't work when I tried that before, maybe because of some other reason.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the rtsp link to `rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream` or replace `mystream` with appropriate path and it worked.

Comment: "or something similar"? Please be accurate when replying.